# How to update Database with LINQ? Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to update a the database via Linq-to-SQL.

I have a table named `Staff_Time_TBL` which has 9 columns. I am trying to update a single columns record on potentially multiple rows.

My LINQ query is as follows. It grabs data from column `Section_Data`from a specified date to another specified date and from a single employees Number.

```
DatabaseDataContext Sql = new DatabaseDataContext(ConnectionString);

var getList = Sql.Staff_Time_TBLs.Where(
               staff => staff.Staff_No == staffNo &&
               staff.Date_Data >= dateFrom &&
               staff.Date_Data <= dateTo)
               .Select(staff => staff.Section_Data).ToList();
```

I am then going to use a `foreach` loop to iterate though the collection and update the database,

```
foreach (var item in getList)
                {                    
                    item.Section_Data = "myValue";
                }
         Sql.SubmitChanges();
```

The problem is that this below , the entity `Section_Data` does not exist.

```
item.Section_Data
```

So, I am thinking that I have not put together the LINQ correctly to be able access the entities? How do I amend the query so as I can access the entity to update the database?

Comment: I'm guessing, but because you select `staff.Section_Data`, it's not likely that you can then do `item.Section_Data`. Perhaps just remove the `Select(...)` part of your code?

Comment: @DavidG, thanks you were correct. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var getList = Sql.Staff_Time_TBLs.Where(
               staff => staff.Staff_No == staffNo &&
               staff.Date_Data >= dateFrom &&
               staff.Date_Data <= dateTo)
               .Select(staff => staff.Section_Data).ToList();
```

This query will give you only data of type Section_Data because you are selecting Section_Data, and when you run a for each on that, you will be able to access the attributes related to that only, hence just remove the select part from the query.

```
var getList = Sql.Staff_Time_TBLs.Where(
               staff => staff.Staff_No == staffNo &&
               staff.Date_Data >= dateFrom &&
               staff.Date_Data <= dateTo)
               .ToList();
```

Now you will be able to access the attributes inside it.

```
foreach (var item in getList)
{                    
   item.Section_Data = "myValue";
}
Sql.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much, I have been fiddling with this for the last few days.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var getList = Sql.Staff_Time_TBLs.Where(
           staff => staff.Staff_No == staffNo &&
           staff.Date_Data >= dateFrom &&
           staff.Date_Data <= dateTo)
           .ToList();
```